# Website domain owner how to find

Tags: domains, domain-registrar, address

My company has a foo.in website but often times people accidentally use foo.com instead.

Now I was interested in buying the foo.com domain name but it comes up as already owned. A whois lookup shows this:

[image]

On the other hand, the foo.com webpage doesn't seem to belong to any legitimate entity. It just looks like this:

[image]

Is this an example of cybersquatting? If so, is godaddy the squatter or someone else? e.g. For some legitimate websites whois shows the Registrant Organization its email address, physical address etc.

But in this case the entry for foo.com doesn't. How do I go about finding who the current owner is?

Comment: I do not like squatting or the whole domain name monetizing business. It is a terrible terrible terrible thing. However, if I own a domain name, I have the right to sell it. Be that as it may, I would guess that this domain name is for sale through GoDaddy. You may want to investigate that. There may be a ready option for purchasing the domain name. Good luck. Cheers!!

Comment: The domain is parked with SEDO, the owner will be generating revenue from visits to the domain. If you want to purchase the domain then you need to purchase it through the SEDO market place.

Comment: @closetnoc Nope. Not available for sale at GoDaddy. The site reports that this domain is already taken.

Comment: @closetnoc What is fishy though is that GoDaddy further offers a "Domain Buy Service" (for a fee, of course) where they say _"We contact the current owner on your behalf. If it's for sale, we'll do all we can to get it for you!"_ So, if I cannot know who the owner is how come GoDaddy knows? I'm not sure.

Comment: @SimonHayter So how does SEDO exactly work? If I check out the domain on SEDO they again offer to be a broker for me & negotiate with the owner. PS. How did you know this domain is parked with SEDO.

Comment: @GoDaddy, just like Google, is a god. Don't you know? ;-) GoDaddy is a registrar which makes them privy to information that may not be available to you or I. Plus, if they call and ask a question, I am sure they will not get blown off like you and I would. Cheers!!

Comment: I could tell because the name servers used. SEDO allows people to sell, buy and monetize domains. You simply change your name servers to theirs and you can generate revenue from people visiting the parked domain. The domain can also be sold on SEDO market place, your get all your answers by visiting SEDO :)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, a Whois lookup I did resulted in the domain being registered at Tucows, not GoDaddy. Tucows is only the registrar, not the owner. The owner is DigiMedia.com, L.P. A three character .COM domain is a very good and very valuable domain name to own. Since the domain is parked, the owner is likely a domain investor. If you're interested in making them an offer for the domain, you can find their contact information in the domain's Whois here: http://whois.domaintools.com/foo.com.

Also this is not an example of cybersquatting. Cybersquatting specifically refers to people who register well-known company or brand names in the hopes of making a profit off of them.

Comment: Thanks. In our case too foo is our registered company name. But true that we aren't "well known".

Answer (score -1):

Domain provider or Hosting providers may hide domain owners details to public and might not found on whosis database. please search in Icann database for any luck. All the best

Comment: The grammar is so bad, that I can't understand this answer.